# C# ILogger in a web form application

Tags: c#

I want log information to a console windows upon page_load.
I have written the line of code:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()).CreateLogger("About");
```

and included the package, using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Informational message");
    }
```

nothing is displayed/ no console windows pops up. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to solve it?

I tried to configure the logger to log to a txt file with no luck.

Comment: Logging to console has no sense in a web forms application. What problems do you have to log a txt file?

Comment: @JesúsLópez logging to the console makes sense in almost all applications. It's the most common logging method in Docker and Kubernetes. There's no other way to find out why the web app failed to start. Console doesn't mean Terminal Window though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos initially I had custom methods that used the stream writer to write to a txt file. I am trying to use illoger  instead of using custom methods.

Comment: `Console` doesn't mean `Terminal Window`. When an application writes to the Console the output goes to whatever is listening on its STDOUT or STDERR stream. That may be a terminal window, another program or nothing. `AddConsole()` tells the logger to write to `STDOUT`, not to start a terminal window. Unfortunately, WebForms only runs on ASP.NET which only runs on IIS which ... discards Console output. You'll have to use another logger to see the log output

Comment: @DevOp77 `use illoger instead of using custom methods.` add a file target then. IIS discards the Console output. A very common option is to use use Serilog's File sink and integrate it with ILogger

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Logs that you can't see are totally useless. Web Forms applications only run on Windows, typically on IIS. How do you redirect standard output of W3WP process to a file?